# Bulk upload log messages to local Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, ibm-cloud, kibana, elastic-stack

We have a few external applications in cloud (IBM Bluemix) which logs its application syslogs in the bluemix logmet service which internally uses the ELK stack.

Now on a periodic basis, we would like to download the logs from the cloud and upload it into a local Elastic/Kibana instance. This is because storing logs in cloud services incurs cost and additional cost if we want to search the same by Kibana. The local elastic instance can delete/flush old logs which we don't need.

The downloaded logs will look like this

```
{"instance_id_str":"0","source_id_str":"APP/PROC/WEB","app_name_str":"ABC","message":"Hello","type":"syslog","event_uuid":"474b78aa-6012-44f3-8692-09bd667c5822","origin_str":"rep","ALCH_TENANT_ID":"3213cd20-63cc-4592-b3ee-6a204769ce16","logmet_cluster":"topic3-elasticsearch_3","org_name_str":"123","@timestamp":"2017-09-29T02:30:15.598Z","message_type_str":"OUT","@version":"1","space_name_str":"prod","application_id_str":"3104b522-aba8-48e0-aef6-6291fc6f9250","ALCH_ACCOUNT_ID_str":"","org_id_str":"d728d5da-5346-4614-b092-e17be0f9b820","timestamp":"2017-09-29T02:30:15.598Z"}

{"instance_id_str":"0","source_id_str":"APP/PROC/WEB","app_name_str":"ABC","message":"EFG","type":"syslog","event_uuid":"d902dddb-afb7-4f55-b472-211f1d370837","origin_str":"rep","ALCH_TENANT_ID":"3213cd20-63cc-4592-b3ee-6a204769ce16","logmet_cluster":"topic3-elasticsearch_3","org_name_str":"123","@timestamp":"2017-09-29T02:30:28.636Z","message_type_str":"OUT","@version":"1","space_name_str":"prod","application_id_str":"dcd9f975-3be3-4451-a9db-6bed1d906ae8","ALCH_ACCOUNT_ID_str":"","org_id_str":"d728d5da-5346-4614-b092-e17be0f9b820","timestamp":"2017-09-29T02:30:28.636Z"}
```

I have created an index in our local elasticsearch as

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/commslog?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "logs" : {
            "properties" : {
                "instance_id_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "source_id_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "app_name_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "message" : { "type" : "text" },
                "type" : { "type" : "text" },
                "event_uuid" : { "type" : "text" },
                "ALCH_TENANT_ID" : { "type" : "text" },
                "logmet_cluster" : { "type" : "text" },
                "org_name_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "@timestamp" : { "type" : "date" },
                "message_type_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "@version" : { "type" : "text" },
                "space_name_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "application_id_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "ALCH_ACCOUNT_ID_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "org_id_str" : { "type" : "text" },
                "timestamp" : { "type" : "date" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Now to bulk upload the file, used the command

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' http://localhost:9200/commslog/logs/_bulk --data-binary '@commslogs.json'
```

The above command throws an error

**Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]**

The solution is to follow the rules for bulk upload as per

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bulk-insert-file-having-many-json-entries-into-elasticsearch/46470/2

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

So i manually changed few of the log statements by adding action before every line

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "commslog", "_type" : "logs" } }
```

This works!!.

Another option was to call the curl command, providing the _idex and _type in the path

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' http://localhost:9200/commslog/logs/_bulk --data-binary '@commslogs.json'
```

but without the action, this too throws the same error

The problem is we cannot do this for thousands of log records we get. Is there an option where once we download the log files from Bluemix and upload the files without adding the action.

**NOTE** We are not using logstash at the moment, but

- is it possible to use logstash and just use grok to transform the
  logs and add the necessary entries?
- How can we bulk upload documents via Logstash?
- Is logstash the ideal solution or we can just write a program to
  transform and do that

Thanks

Comment: Filebeat should be able to write json logs straight to your local elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks @AlainCollins. I did try Filebeats and was able to upload logs directly into ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alain Collins said, you should be able to use filebeat directly.

For logstash:

- it should be possible to use logstash, but rather than using grok, you should use the json codec/filter, it would be *much* easier.
- You can use the file input with logstash to process many files and wait for it to finish (to know when it's finished, use a file/stdout, possibly with the dot codec, and wait for it to stop writing).
- Instead of just transforming the files with logstash, you should directly upload to elasticsearch (with the elasticsearch output).

As for your problem, I think it will be much easier to just use a small program to add the missing action line or use filebeat, unless you are experimented enough with logstash config to write and logstash config quicker than a program adding one line everywhere in the document.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the multiple solution. I tried both options (small script and filebeats) and was able to upload logs with that. With file beats there is more configuration needed to support the same index and type instead of using the filebeat's default index. I for the time being decided to go with the script                                                                                 sed 'h;s/.*/{ "index" : { "_index" : "commslog", "_type" : "logs" } }/;G' logs .json   to add the index line before each line . Once we plan to automate this process we can use filebeats. Thanks

Comment: @Tatha You're welcome. While I agree it was possible to use logstash or filebeat, I think you're better off with a simple solution.